# How to split a camelCase string into an array in awk?

Tags: arrays, awk, split, camelcasing

How can I split a camelCase string into an array in awk using the split function?

Input:

```
STRING="camelCasedExample"
```

Desired Result:

```
WORDS[1]="camel"
WORDS[2]="Cased"
WORDS[3]="Example"
```

Bad Attempt:

```
split(STRING, WORDS, /([a-z])([A-Z])/);
```

Bad Result:

```
WORDS[1]="came"
WORDS[2]="ase"
WORDS[3]="xample"
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't do it with `split()` alone which is why GNU awk has `patsplit()`:

```
$ awk 'BEGIN {
    patsplit("camelCasedExample",words,/(^|[[:upper:]])[[:lower:]]+/)
    for ( i in words ) print words[i]
}'
camel
Cased
Example
```

Comment: This is what I was looking for!  I was not aware of the patsplit command and it was not supported by gawk 3.1.8 on my older dev server, but I was able to make use of it with my newer server which has gawk 4.2.1.

Answer (score 2):

With your shown samples, please try following. Written and tested in GNU `awk` should work in any `awk`. This will create array named `words` whose values could be accessed from index starting 1,2,3 and so on. I am printing it as an output, you can make use of it later on as per your wish too.

```bash
awk -F'=|"' -v s1="\"" '
{
  gsub(/[A-Z]/,"\n&",$3)
  val=(val?val ORS:"")$3
}
END{
  num=split(val,words,ORS)
  for(i=1;i<=num;i++){
    if(words[i]!=""){
      print "WORDS[" ++count "]=" s1 words[i] s1
    }
  }
}
' Input_file
```

***Explanation:*** Adding detailed explanation for above `awk` code.

```
awk -F'=|"' -v s1="\"" '                     ##Starting awk program, setting field separator as = OR " and setting s1 to " here.
{
  gsub(/[A-Z]/,"\n&",$3)                     ##Using gsub to globally substitute captial letter with new character and value itself in 3rd field.
  val=(val?val ORS:"") $3                    ##Creating val which has $3 in it and keep adding values in val itself.
}
END{                                         ##Starting END block of this program from here.
  num=split(val,words,ORS)                     ##Splitting val into array arr with delmiter of ORS.
  for(i=1;i<=num;i++){                       ##Running for loop from value of 1 to till num here.
    if(words[i]!=""){                          ##Checking if arr item is NOT NULL then do following.
       print "WORDS[" ++count "]=" s1 words[i] s1    ##Printing WORDS[ value of i followed by ]= followed by s1 words[i] value and s1.
    }
  }
}
'  Input_file                                ##Mentioning Input_file name here.
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is an `awk` solution that would work with any version of `awk`:

```bash
s='camelCasedExample'
awk '{
   while (match($0, /(^|[[:upper:]])[[:lower:]]+/)) {
      wrd = substr($0,RSTART,RLENGTH)
      print wrd
      # you can also store it in array
      arr[++n] = wrd
      $0 = substr($0,RSTART+RLENGTH)
   }
}' <<< "$s"

camel
Cased
Example
```

Answer (score 0):

> ```
> echo 'camelCasedExample' | 
>
> mawk '{ for (_=(____=split($((_=_<_) * gsub("[>-[]",
>             (___)"&")), __, ___) )^_; _<=____; _++) {
>
>         print "","__["(_)"]",__[_] } }' OFS=' :: ' FS='^$' ___='\20\22'
> ```

```
 :: __[1] :: camel
 :: __[2] :: Cased
 :: __[3] :: Example
```